# SQL: how to join multiple queries together?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've got a table of purchasing decisions that looks like this:

```
org_id    item_id    spend
--------------------------
123        AAB         2
123        AAC         4
124        AAB        10
124        AAD         5
```

I want to find all the items that were only bought by three or fewer organisations, then I want to order them by summed spend, along with the IDs of the organisations.

This is my query for getting the items in that list:

```
SELECT
  item_id,
  EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT(org) AS org_count,
  SUM(spend) AS total_spend
FROM
  [mytable]
GROUP BY
   item_id
HAVING
  org_count < 4
ORDER BY
  total_spend DESC
```

It gives me results that look like this:

```
item_id    total_spend
--------------------------
AAB         12
AAC         4
AAD         5
```

But I need to extend this query to also return the IDs of those organisations.

Is this possible in a single query, or do I need to do it in multiple queries?

The query for getting the IDs of the organisations on their own would look like:

```
SELECT 
  org 
FROM 
  mytable
WHERE item_id IN (SELECT item_id ... etc, query as above)
```

But I'm not sure how to glue the two together.

UPDATE: Ideally I'd end up with something a lot like the original table, but only containing those items bought by three or fewer organisations:

```
org_id    item_id    spend
--------------------------
123        AAB         2
123        AAC         4
124        AAB        10
124        AAD         5
```

Comment: you then would have multiple rows for each item id -- can you please show what you expect the final result to look like?

Comment: Apologies, yes multiple rows for each item/org combo are fine. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try query like this. In the result set you will see all items that were bought by there or fewer organisations and total spend

```
SELECT T2.org_id,
       T.item_id
FROM table AS T2
JOIN
    (SELECT item_id,
           SUM(spend) AS total_spend 
    FROM table AS T
    GROUP BY T.item_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT org_id) < 4) AS T ON T.item_id = T2.item_id
ORDER BY T.total_spend DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, this set me down the right track. I had to use `EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT` again for BigQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is sort-of `GROUP_CONCAT()`.  But, there is no `DISTINCT` option in bigquery.  So, use a subquery:

```
SELECT item_id, COUNT(*) AS org_count,
       SUM(io_spend) AS total_spend,
       GROUP_CONCAT(org, ', ') as orgs
FROM (SELECT item_id, org, SUM(spend) as io_spend
      FROM t
      GROUP BY item_id, org
     ) io
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING org_count < 4
ORDER BY total_spend DESC;
```

EDIT:

If you are content with the ids in separate rows, then following is a SQL version that might work in Bigquery:

```
SELECT item_id, org,
       SUM(spend) as org_spend,
       SUM(SUM(spend)) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id) as total_spend,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY item_id) as numOrgs
FROM t
GROUP BY item_id, org
HAVING numOrgs < 4;
```

Comment: `ORDER BY SUM(total_spend) DESC`?

Comment: ok not 100% with BigQuery Gordon but shouldn't Having and Order By use a aggregated or grouped by column like other SQLs? That is SUM(io_spend) and COUNT(*)

Comment: Thanks! Separate rows are fine, but with the second query I get `Error: Expression 'spend' is not present in the GROUP BY list`.

Comment: ...which is weird, since it's an aggregation and that should be allowed?https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#groupby

Comment: If I remove the `SUM` fields I also get `Error: Field 'numOrgs' not found`, I guess BigQuery doesn't like it.

Comment: @Richard . . . Bigquery needs to use aliases or column names for the `order by`.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery - **JOIN**s sometimes is quite a headache (depends on multiple factors), so it is always good to have some non-join solutions in your arsenal.

Below are few examples of such based on [Window functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#windowfunctions) :
I think they can be interesting both from practical and learning prospective

Option #1 -  with group_concat/regexp trick

```
SELECT org_id, item_id, spend
FROM (
  SELECT org_id, item_id, spend,
    GROUP_CONCAT(STRING(org_id)) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id) AS orgs
  FROM table
)
WHERE 1 + LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(orgs, r'[^,]', '')) < 4
ORDER BY item_id, org_id
```

Option #2 - assuming on avarage number of organizations per item is not too big (so count distinct is more less exact):

```
SELECT org_id, item_id, spend
FROM (
  SELECT org_id, item_id, spend,
    COUNT(DISTINCT org_id) OVER(PARTITION BY item_id) AS orgs
  FROM table
)
WHERE orgs < 4
ORDER BY item_id, org_id
```